Explicit construction of a countable model of ZF set theory
So, having superficially skimmed books on logic and set theory, set theory still feels vague and circular to me.
So, I would like to make it concrete.
I do not doubt the existence of countable sets which i can write down ("enumerate") explicitly, and since Lowenheim-Skolem theorem assures us there is a countable model of ZF set theory, my question is whether one can point out an algorithm to create a model for ZF set theory as an explicit countable set of strings, with an explicit relation "an element of", defined in a way that one can verify whether or not it holds for any two two such strings.
And if not, why not.

It sounds like you are looking for a computable model of ZF. They do not exist.

@spaceisdarkgreen the BB function is uncomputable; still, it is explicitly defined. Is there a similar in spirit construction of a countable model of ZF set theory?

That depends on how general of a notion of "explicit" you are allowing. First, note that without assuming the consistency of ZF (something that is not provable in ZFC), we can't show there is a model at all. Allowing that, there are a number of ways to produce a well-defined countable model of ZF (i.e. its not some pure existence proof using the axiom of choice, or anything like that), even ones that are relatively "simple" according to some complexity criteria.

But in terms of having some transparent membership relation you can "get your hands around", not really, as far as I'm aware. One could push further in consistency strength to assume there are transitive models of ZF and then some $L_\alpha$ (levels of the constructible hierarchy) will be transitive models of ZFC, and the least such $\alpha$ is a well-defined countable ordinal for which $L_\alpha$ is a countable model and the membership relation is just the (actual) membership relation, but this $\alpha$ does not have a simple combinatorial description.

See this answer of mine. Basically, not only is there no computable model of ZF, the more "correct" we demand a model of ZF to be the (drastically) more complicated they become - e.g. there isn't even a hyperarithmetic model of ZF in which the natural numbers are all standard.

@NoahSchweber "since ZFC is a computable theory, building a model of ZFC is no harder than building a nonstandard model of PA" - sorry for my ignorance, in which sense ZFC is a computable theory?

@curious The set of ZFC axioms is a computable set (see here). The set of all ZFC theorems is a c.e. but not computable set.

There is an elegant interpretation of finite set theory (e.g. ZFC minus the axiom of infinity) in arithmetic: define $n \mathrel{\epsilon} m$ to hold iff the $n$-th bit of the binary representation of $m$ is $1$. Thus $0$ codes $\emptyset$, $1$ codes ${ \emptyset }$, $2$ codes ${ { \emptyset } }$, $3$ codes ${ \emptyset, { \emptyset } }$, and so on. Of course, infinite sets cannot be coded as such, but maybe this clears up some of the "vagueness" you are worried about?
